# Issue with the notch in Oreo? W/HwNotchSizeUtil: calculateSize error

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

The exact message is:

> --------- beginning of system 06-29 18:08:19.479 1591-1591/? W/HwNotchSizeUtil: calculateSize error mRogWidth = 0mRogWHeigth = 0,
>   mDefaultWidth = 1080

The message is not systematic but when it starts I've got many.

I'm using a honor 10 with a notch and I have a widget which creates a `NotificationChannel.`

Could it be due to this?